# Regex for MetaCafe

Tags: php, regex, embed

I'm trying to integrate the PHP script AutoEmbed, however I noticed that the regular expression for MetaCafe is not up-to-date. Can I get some help please.

```
array(
    'title' => 'MetaCafe',
    'website' => 'http://www.metacafe.com',
    'url-match' => 'http://(?:www\.)?metacafe\.com/(?:watch|fplayer)/(\w{1,10})/',
    'embed-src' => 'http://www.metacafe.com/fplayer/$2/metacafe.swf',
    'embed-width' => '400',
    'embed-height' => '345',
  ),
```

The regular expression works fine for this:
http://www.metacafe.com/watch/8145782/inbred_official_trailer_2012/

But not for this:
http://www.metacafe.com/watch/mv-Qp52/who_is_he/

I think it may be to do with the 'mv-Qp52' part containing a dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the dash is not included in `\w`.
You can manually fix the regex by adding the dash to the allowed characters set:

`http://(?:www\.)?metacafe\.com/(?:watch|fplayer)/([\w\-]{1,10})/`

Comment: Thanks I chose this one because I wanted to validate the URL as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, so my suggestion is to accept all characters except the slash (`/`).

Use `http://(?:www\.)?metacafe\.com/(?:watch|fplayer)/([^/]+)/`.